# not able to delete database in postgres

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

[image]

The `drop database` command is not working in sql shell. It shows db doesn't exists. But `pgadmin` and `\l` shows the db. What is the problem and how to delete the db?

Comment: The error message is `database "mydatabase" does not exist`, because the database is named `"myDatabase"`. When quoting identifiers, case matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing `"myDatabase"` (with quotation marks "") since your name is case-sensitive.
In general it is better to use lower-case names in postgres and I think in unix in general.

Comment: yes. The quotation was missing.

Answer (score -2):

1.`find . -path "/migrations/.py" -not -name "init.py" -delete`

2.`find . -path "/migrations/.pyc" -delete`
[Instead of first 2 steps,you can
manually deleting all the files except init.py from migrations folder in all app.]

3.`sudo su postgres`

4.`psql`

5. `DROP DATABASE databasename;`

6.`\q`

7.`createdb databasename`

8.`psql`

9.`grant all privileges on database databasename to username;`

10.`\q`

11.`exit`

12.`source venv/bin/activate`

13.`python manage.py makemigrations`

14.`python manage.py migrate`

15. `python manage.py createsuperuser`
16. `python manage.py runserver`